# setInterval not updating with variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, setinterval, var

When I run the code it only intervals at the initial variable I created "2000". When i click on the button it doesn't change the interval to "50". Does anyone know why?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="pressme"> Press me! </h1>
    </body>

    <script>
    amount = 2000;
    var i = 1;
    document.getElementById("pressme").onclick = function() {
        amount = 50;
    }
        function doSomething() {
            i++;
            console.log("I did something! " + i);
        }
        setInterval(doSomething, amount)
    </script>
</html>
```

This isn't the OG code, more a simplified version of it.

Comment: Your problem is `setInterval` fires right away, before the click Event, so the `amount` stays at `2000`. If you want an interval to change timing, it won't. You can assign the interval to a variable and `clearInterval(interval)` then create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval was already set with the 2s, if you change the variable after that, it won't make any difference.

I recommend you do this:

```
let amount = 2000;
let interval = setInterval(doSomething, amount);

var i = 1;
document.getElementById("pressme").onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    amount = 50;
    setInterval(doSomething, amount);
}
function doSomething() {
    i++;
    console.log("I did something! " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use setInterval with clearInterval together.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="pressme"> Press me! </h1>
    </body>

    <script>
        amount = 2000;
        var i = 1;
        var handler
        document.getElementById("pressme").onclick = function() {
            amount = 50;
            clearInterval(handler);
            handler = setInterval(doSomething, amount);
        }
        function doSomething() {
            i++;
            console.log("I did something! " + i);
        }
        handler = setInterval(doSomething, amount);
    </script>
```

So when click button, you should remove original setInterval handler and recreate it.